# Generating RESTful responses with Laravel 4

Tags: php, json, angularjs, rest, laravel-4

I'm building an application with AngularJS that talks to a REST API developed in Laravel 4.

I've made a good start so far by having each request send the relevant Access-Control headers that allow Angular to talk to the API, and I've also built a `UserController` resource:

```
Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
```

However now I seem to be facing a wall. For the learning opportunities, I'd like to build this REST API properly using good standards, and I'm trying to work out how to do the responses.

I know I want to return JSON from the API and as far as I know I should wrap every response in a `data` field, and I also realize I can do that using something like this at the bottom of my controller actions:

```
return Response::json(array(
    'data' => array(
            'users' => array(
                array(
                    'username' => 'Bob',
                    'email' => 'bob@gmail.com'
                )
            )
        ),
        'status' => 200,
        'success' => true
    ),
    200
);
```

However, I don't want to repeat that kind of logic in every controller action in my application, so I'm wondering how I can make that code more DRY so that at the end of my controller I can just do something like this:

```
return array(
    'users' => array(
        array(
            'username' => 'Bob',
            'email' => 'bob@gmail.com'
        )
    )
);
```

and somewhere else in my application I can do the `Response::json` stuff. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So like you said, you want to return a JSON response, for example:

```
return Response::json(
        array(
            'status' => 'success',
            'pages' => $modelData->toArray()
        ),
        200
    );
```

So, instead of repeating this everytime, you could just make a createResponse...() function, perhaps in a base controller class, that you can call in all your controllers. A response failed function could look something like:

```
function createResponseFailed() {
    return Response::json([
        'error' => [
            'message' => 'Some failed message' 
        ]
    ], 404);
}
```

That is just a simple example, but illustrates the point. Hope it helps!